# Set specific date into Default Value in SQL 2008 Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to add specific date ('0001-01-01') into Default Value or Binding for date data type in sql 2008 server. So, when I adding the new record I'd like to sql set 0001-01-01 date automatically without setting this value inside sql statement from aspx script. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you should accept this answer. There is a little green checkbox under the voting. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for additional assistance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT [date_def_constraint]  DEFAULT ('0001-01-01') FOR [your_column]
```